# KerasTuner - RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to train my Conve net with the help of `kerastuner==1.0.1` and I ran into `RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build model`, can't seem to fix it. Can anyone help me out with this? Thank You!

My Conve Net Model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(hp.Int('input_units',
                                min_value=32,
                                max_value=256,
                                step=32), (3, 3), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

for i in range(hp.Int('n_layers', 1, 4)):  
    model.add(Conv2D(hp.Int(f'conv_{i}_units',
                                min_value=32,
                                max_value=256,
                                step=32), (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="adam",
                  loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Comment: Kindly include minimum reproducible code for your error. Thanks.

Comment: What is `x_train`? Is it a Numpy array? If so, what is its shape?